# How to use click function using clj webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, clojure

Can I use `click` funtion after finding element using `find-element` function using clj-webdriver.
Like,

```
(click (find-element { :tag :a :class "foo"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am looking through the [element API documentation](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Element-API) and have not tested this.

`click` on a element works as long as the found element is a [form element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp) (e.g., button; input). So if your code above does not work, that is probably because it is not a form element. You can, however, use `(click "a.foo")` directly.